# Spring Mvc Multiple record fetching Example

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am new to Spring.I am trying to fetch multiple records on DAO and Then Send it back to service and then controller layer, after Controller it need to be display on the JSP page. I Do not want to use JDBC Template how can I code. ??

```
public ArrayList<userBean> Manage() 
{
    ArrayList<userBean> list = new ArrayList<userBean>();
    System.out.println("manage from dao");
    try
    {
        con=DbConnection.getConnection();
        ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_info");
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            ub= new userBean();
            ub.setNAME(rs.getString("name"));
            ub.setLASTNAME(rs.getString("lastname"));
            ub.setPASSWORD(rs.getString("password"));
            list.add(ub);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    return list;
}
```

Above is my code from DAO Layer.
userBaen is my bean class.
the JSP page which I Want to display is loading without result.
Following is my JSP Code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Manage Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="l">
<tr>
                <td>${l.name}</td>
                <td>${l.lastname}</td>
                <td>${l.password}</td>
</tr>

</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Here's a few suggestions: 1) read the site rules, bcz this question is not allowed. 2) learn to read directions in general as it can help in concepts such as this. 3) come back once you have some code you'd like help with...

Comment: Thank you for explaining the vote down.  So many people vote down questions but give no response to why.  It's good to see someone actually cares to teach others how to help others help this site.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the error . .
below is my code from DAO Which works for me

```
public ArrayList<userBean> Manage() 
    { 
        HttpServletRequest req = null;
        HttpServletResponse res;

        ArrayList<userBean> list = new ArrayList<userBean>();
        System.out.println("manage from dao");
        try
        {
            con=DbConnection.getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_info");
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                ub= new userBean();
                ub.setNAME(rs.getString("name"));
                ub.setLASTNAME(rs.getString("lastname"));
                ub.setPASSWORD(rs.getString("password"));
                list.add(ub);
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        return list;
    }
```

on controller

```
public ModelAndView Manage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        Bean bean = new Bean();
        Dao d= new Dao();

        try
        {
            List<userBean> rows=d.Manage();
            request.setAttribute("rows", rows);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("manageResult");

    }
```

On JSP Page

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
           <%@taglib  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <jsp:useBean id="TimeDetailBean" class="com.logic.bean.userBean"   scope="application" />
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Manage Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <h1>The Employee_Info Results </h1>
    <table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Password</th></tr>
    <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="row">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value=${row.NAME}></td><td><input type="text" name="lastname" value=${row.LASTNAME}></td><td><input type="text" name="password" value=${row.PASSWORD}></td><td><a href="update.do">UPDATE</a><td><a href="delete.do">DELETE</a></td>
    </tr>

    </c:forEach>
    </table>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```